# How to parse stdClass object?

Tags: php

I have a SOAP response whose var_dump looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)[14]
  public 'GetClientsResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[15]
```

I can't figure out how to parse this for the life of me, I've never used stdClass before.

How can I parse this response in PHP?

Comment: `stdClass` is a generic class object used to [store data in an object instead of an array](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/).

Comment: @arxanas: It's also one of the stupidest ideas PHP developers ever had.

Comment: @Truth: I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you can cast it into an array (assuming the object is stored in `$response`):

```
$response = (array) $response;
```

Or you can access things by:

```
$response->GetClientResult->otherStuff;
```

Comment: Ah, turns out I was missing some parameters to the SOAP call. Fixed now...ugh.

Answer (score 1):

An `StdClass` is an empty class where you can set and get property values. An example:

```
 <?php
 // $response is a normal array
 $response['GetClientResult'] = 'foo'; // set
 $response['GetClientResult']; // get

 // $response is a StdClass
 $response->GetClientResult = 'foo'; // set
 $response->GetClientResult; // get
 ?>
```

And if you want to cast the class back to an array you can use:

```
$response = (array) $response
```

And if you want to do that recursive, because you have multiple StdClasses:

```
function StdClass2array(StdClass $class)
{
    $array = array();

    foreach ($class as $key => $item)
    {
            if ($item instanceof StdClass) {
                    $array[$key] = StdClass2array($item);
            } else {
                    $array[$key] = $item;
            }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: The array conversion is just what I needed. Thanks!